# Jenkins on Kubernetes - Get logs of containers from kubectl

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins

I start this question with the doubt if this belongs here or to StackOverflow; I'll give a try here ,the problem is the following:

I'm working with Jenkins on Kubernetes and I'm not able to retrieve the logs of containers used on the pipelines. 
For example using the following pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      containerTemplate { name 'alpine' image 'alpine' command 'tail -f /dev/null'}
    }
  }
  stages { 
      stage('sample'){
          steps{
              container('alpine'){
                echo "Hello world"
                sleep 600
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

everything works fine and I can see "Hello world" printed on Jenkins console, but I'd also like to get it as output from the command `kubectl get logs pod-name -c alpine`. I suppose that `kubectl logs` display what is written on `stdout`/`stderr` by the command used as *entrypoint* in the container ( `tail -f /dev/null` in this case ) and that that's the reason a I don't get "Hello world", but I don't get how to achieve what I want.

I also saw a workaround suggested on Docker documentation :

> The official nginx image creates a symbolic link from
> /var/log/nginx/access.log to /dev/stdout, and creates another symbolic
> link from /var/log/nginx/error.log to /dev/stderr, overwriting the log
> files and causing logs to be sent to the relevant special device
> instead. See the Dockerfile.

but I don't think that solution fits my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
containerTemplate { name 'alpine', image 'alpine', ttyEnabled: true, command 'cat' }
```

Reference: https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#container-group-support

Comment: I'm using declarative pipeline, and by specifying both `tty` and `command` directly on pod's yaml doesn't work.

Comment: Same idea [Here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#declarative-pipeline)

Comment: I'm actually not using declarative but I think the command should be `cat` since `tail -f /dev/null` is tailing nothing.